# FOR/AFTER in SQL triggers

Tags: sql, sql-server, triggers

I am newbie in SQL. I am reading about Triggers in SQL.I have got almost about Triggers. But in DML Triggers, we use FOR/AFTER keyword. I didn't get difference between FOR/AFTER and why we use FOR/AFTER keyword. I have already read on MSDN but didn't get the simple answer.
Can anyone explain me what is it?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

There is no difference between using FOR and AFTER.

I believe the original (pre 2000) syntax only used the FOR keyword. However, when [INSTEAD OF](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa213995%28v=SQL.80%29.aspx) triggers were introduced, the "FOR" keyword could seem quite confusing. "AFTER" more accurately conveys the type of trigger, and is more easily distinguished from "INSTEAD OF".

---

An INSTEAD OF trigger would be used if we wanted to transform what was inserted into the table, or prevent an insertion from taking place.

An AFTER trigger would more normally be used if we wanted to perform additional tasks, based on what has just occurred. For instance, you could have an "AFTER DELETE" trigger, that copied deleted rows into some kind of archive table. Basically, in an AFTER trigger, you more normally do still want the activity to occur.

Comment: thank you for the reply.Like in Instead of trigger, we can avoid the script which written by user and we can use our script.So can you tell me why we use FOR|AFTER

Answer (score 4):

From [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms179304.aspx):

*AFTER triggers are never executed if a constraint violation occurs; therefore, these triggers cannot be used for any processing that might prevent constraint violations.*

And [then](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms175943.aspx):

*You can request AFTER triggers by specifying either the AFTER or FOR keywords. Because the FOR keyword has the same effect as AFTER, DML triggers with the FOR keyword are also classified as AFTER triggers*

It would seem there is no difference.

Comment: thank you for the reply.Like in Instead of trigger, we can avoid the script which written by user and we can use our script.So can you tell me why we use FOR|AFTER

Comment: Well, that is why I posted the first citation. The `AFTER` trigger is executed *after* the action occurs, but only when it succeeds, not if it fails due to for example a constraint violation. The `INSTEAD OF` trigger replaces the action and can thus also prevent the action.

Answer (score 2):

If I interpret your comments to the other answers correctly, you want to know why or when one uses the "FOR|AFTER" keywords.

It's simple: there are two kinds of triggers, the AFTER-trigger and the INSTEAD-OF-trigger.
The INSTEAD-OF-trigger for e.g. an insert action can be written as

```
create trigger myTrigger on myTable
INSTEAD OF insert
begin
    (... code goes here ...)
end
```

and the AFTER-trigger can be written as either

```
create trigger myTrigger on myTable
AFTER insert
begin
    (... code goes here ...)
end
```

or

```
create trigger myTrigger on myTable
FOR insert
begin
    (... code goes here ...)
end
```

As Damien_The_Unbeliever mentions, the AFTER keyword is more readable than the FOR version, that is all.

Comment: BTW, what do you mean by "we can avoid the script which written by user and we can use our script"?

Answer (score 1):

They are the same. See this excerpt from BOL
"
FOR | AFTER 
AFTER specifies that the DML trigger is fired only when all operations specified in the triggering SQL statement have executed successfully. All referential cascade actions and constraint checks also must succeed before this trigger fires.

AFTER is the default when FOR is the only keyword specified.

AFTER triggers cannot be defined on views. 
"

Comment: thank you for the reply.Like in Instead of trigger, we can avoid the script which written by user and we can use our script.So can you tell me why we use FOR|AFTER

Answer (score 0):

According to what I observe, FOR is used in DDL trigger while AFTER is used in DML triggers. They have same way of working.